# char* array keeps being set to nullptr

Tags: c++, pointers, getline, atoi

Here is my code:

```
int main () 

{
    const int MAX = 10;
    char *buffer = nullptr;       // used to get input to initialize numEntries
    int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;            // default is 20 entries

    int numEntries;
    success = false;

    while (!success)
    {
        delete buffer;
        buffer = nullptr;
        buffer =  new char [MAX];

        cout << "How many data entries:\t";
        cin.getline(buffer, MAX, '\n');

        cout << endl << endl;

        while (*buffer)
        {
            if (isdigit(*buffer++))
                success = true;
            else
        {       
               success = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}

numEntries = atoi(buffer);
```

The problem is that when I enter a any number, it just displays "numEntries = 0", and it crashes if I enter a string.

Can someone explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: Delete arrays with `delete []`

Comment: You'd have less troubles using a `std::string` instead of a `char*` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Your code doesn't match the question: where do you print "numEntries = ??" ? Also your while loop is buggy `success` will be set according to the last char in the array, not the whole thing.

Comment: This code is simply broken. You allocate an array of `char` and store it in `buffer`, but then you move `buffer` to point somewhere else. Calling `delete` on it later is simply undefined behaviour (and it should be `delete[]`, since you allocated an array).

Comment: Also, you increment the `buffer` every time you check for `isdigit`. If all the characters are digits, you get out bound at the end and then you are trying to delete that value of `buffer` in the next iteration, not the actual base pointer of that array.

Comment: @rajraj Calling `delete` (or `delete[]`) on a null pointer is a guaranteed no-op, no need to check beforehand.

Comment: @Angew I'm very new at this so it would be great if you explained:

- where does the buffer point somewhere else?
- I was told to use delete when allocating memory. Should I be doing something else?

Comment: @Bbvarghe `*buffer++` increments the `buffer` pointer. So it points somewhere else. `new` must be paired with `delete`, `new[]` must be paired with `delete[]`. See also KazDragon's answer.

Comment: @Angew *buffer++ is supposed to traverse the buffer array. should it be while(*(buffer++))?

Comment: @Bbvarghe It traverses the array *by moving the `buffer` pointer to successive elements.* This is pretty basic stuff - you should probably pick up a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
  ^                         ^
  |                         |
 Start                     End
```

- `Start` is the pointer returned from the `new []` expression.
- The second while loop `while (*buffer)` iteratively moves the pointer to the position denoted by `End`.
- `End` is passed to `delete`.  This is wrong.  `Start` wants to be passed to `delete`.

What you may want to do is store a second pointer to the result of the `new []` expression to be used with `delete` (which should also be `delete []`)  For example:

```
int main () 
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    char *buffer = nullptr;       // used to get input to initialize numEntries
    char *bufferptr = nullptr;    // <- ADDED
    int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;            // default is 20 entries

    int index = 0;
    success = false;

    while (!success)
    {
        delete [] bufferptr; // <- CHANGED
        buffer = nullptr;
        buffer =  new char [MAX];
        bufferptr = buffer; // <- ADDED

        cout << "How many data entries:\t";
        cin.getline(buffer, MAX, '\n');

        cout << endl << endl;

        while (*buffer)
        {
            if (isdigit(*buffer++))
                success = true;
            else
                success = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does deleting bufferptr delete buffer?

Comment: @Bbvarghe Because you set `bufferptr` to `buffer` before moving `buffer` away. So `bufferptr` will point to the dynamic array which needs deleting. See also my comment on books, directly at the question.

Comment: So, that means buffer = new char [MAX]' is not setting buffer to an array of pointers where each index points to a different character of the string, but rather it stores the pointer for an array of chars that holds the string

Comment: @Bbvarghe Precisely.  And since you move that pointer during the second while loop, it cannot be used in the delete operation.  My proposed change caches the original pointer returned by new[], which is then passed to delete[].